# How to get value Column A that have value in Column B and put in other Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

- I have 2 columns, `A` and `B`.
- Column `A` is the list of people, column `B` is the list of numbers.
- In column `A` there are 20 cell values, and in column `B` there are 7 cell values.

I want to take out the names of people that have number and put it in other cell. The plan is I put first people that have number in cell `F4`, and then I put next people that have number in cell `H6` and so on.

So my question is: How do I get the first cell value in Column `A` that has a value in Column `B` to put in a cell, and then the next value in Column `A` that has a value in Column `B` in another cell that totally random but the process is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

In **C1** enter the *array formula* :

```
= MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(B:B), 0)
```

in **C2** enter the *array formula*:

```
= MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(INDIRECT("B" & C1+1 & ":B9999")), 0)+C1
```

and copy down.  Column **C** tells us in which rows the names are.  In **D1** enter the normal formula:

```
=INDEX(A:A,C1)
```

and copy down.

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.